# Keys of the keyboard of MacBook Pro don't work as expected

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook-pro

After a system crash, some keys of the keyboard of my MacBook Pro don't work as expected.

When I press the Return key or when I press the 0 key I always get "0return" (a zero and a new line).

The only moment when this work is when I restart the Mac and enter the login password.

This problem started in El Capitan and continue in macOS Sierra.

EDIT
Additional info: for both the Return key and the 0 key, if I keep them pressed they produce a series of new lines (and not new-line zero). Also, I done a test with an external BT keyboard and all works fine.

Comment: Try it from safe boot &/or make a new admin account & see if it persists.

Comment: Thank you for the post Tetsujin. Tried, safe reboot and new admin account don't show behaviour changes. What I noticed is that this problem is not present only in the login window when I turn on the Mac (and not when I reboot it, as I thought).

Comment: What were you doing immediately before the crash?

Comment: I Peanut, I pressed and hold the start button until the Mac is turned off.

Comment: @Cue Have you resolved this issue? By yourself or visiting Applecare ?

Answer (score 0):

The two main things I would do are reset you PRAM/NVRAM and reset your SMC. Below are the steps you need to take.

**Reset your PRAM/NVRAM**

Older Macs had what's called Parameter RAM (PRAM), newer Macs use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). Here’s how to reset your PRAM/NVRAM:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. **Press the power button *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.** You have to make sure you press these keys before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. **Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.**

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. mouse speed, time and date/timezone, etc).

**Reset the SMC**

Your computer's System Management Controller (SMC) can also be reset. The instructions for resetting your SMC depend on three things:

- Does your device run from a built-in battery?
- Does your device run from a removable battery?
- Does your device just run off power from the wall?

Depending on the model of MacBook Pro you have, it'll fall into one of the first two categories. Choose the one below that applies to you.

**For MacBook Pros, MacBook Airs, and MacBooks where you can’t remove the battery on your own (i.e. it's a built-in battery), here’s what you do:**

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the MagSafe adapter (power cable) **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power</kbd> button
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the <kbd>power</kbd> button.

**For MacBook Pros, MacBooks etc that you can remove the battery from, here’s what you do:**

1. Shut down your computer
2. **Disconnect** the MagSafe plug (power cable) from the computer
3. Remove the battery
4. Press the power button for 5 seconds and release
5. Put the battery back in
6. Reconnect the MagSafe cord (or power cable)
7. Turn your computer back on with the power button

Hope this helps. Please report back and let us know.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately neither of these took effect on the keyboard. A new thing I've noticed is that both the Return key and the 0 key, if I keep them pressed they produce a series of new lines, instead of new-line zeros.